# How to remove users from login list

Tags: 18.04

Okay, So I have read a few articles that suggest to put the user in ignore list of gdm or something.

The issue is I have multiple users created for ftp purpose and many gets created & deleted occasionally. So adding each user every time is what I'm trying to avoid.

I wan't to show only my user and don't display any other, or don't show users of `apache-dev` group in login list.

If it's possible please guide.

User are added using the following command:

```
sudo useradd -m -G apache-dev dev1
```

Comment: Can you give them a user id below 1000?

Comment: @Rinzwind Considering I don't have to do manual work, I can. But I've no idea what uid under 1000 means or how it will effect user or my site.

Comment: Try this: edit `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/[username]` and set `SystemAccount` to `true`.

Comment: @Jos I see only 2 accounts, mine & gdm but not dev1 account in the above directory. Okay, did that to my user account & did restart yet see no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `useradd` command, specify the `-r` option. This creates a system account, i.e., an account with a user id below 1000. As a result, these will not appear in the GDM login screen.

Comment: I see, this seems really neat & what I require, But I read somewhere that these accounts are used for scrpts/servers, these cannot log in nor logout if needed. But I don't need a regular user, these are just for the sake of FTP users only. Let  me do some test. If it works, Then awesome, Thanks to you.